# `-': nil can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)

Tags: ruby

In my program Im getting an error which says ./ruby_camping.rb:91:in `-': nil can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError). What I would like to do is to checkout a guest that I have just checked in. Here is the block of code for the checkout part:

```
def self.check_out 
  puts "Welcome to checkout!"
  puts $camping.current_guests
  puts " Here are the current guests, who do you want to checkout?!" 
  puts "State plot number "
  plot = gets.chomp.to_i
  guest = $camping.current_guests[plot-1] 
  puts "State the date for your checkout (a number bigger then " + guest.arrived.to_s + "): "
  # it should not be possible for a guest to checkout before she has checked in
  departureDate = gets.chomp.to_i
  guestStayedDays = departureDate - guest.arrived #Days the guest has stayed
  while (guestStayedDays < 1) do                        
   puts "The date for checkout is not valid. The guest checked in " + guest.arrived.to_s
   puts "Please state a new date."
   departureDate = gets.chomp.to_i
   guestStayedDays = departureDate - guest.arrived
  end       
  guest.departure = departureDate
  guest.plot.increase(guestStayedDays) # increases the electricity meter
  puts guest # prints the guest
  $camping.current_guests[plot-1] = nil # emptys the plot
 end
end
```

How come departureDate still is nil? Thankful for help!

Answer (score 27):

To get a more detailed answer, you would have to indicate which line was line 91 in your program. However to point you in the right direction, if you're seeing `nil can't be coerced into Fixnum` then it means something on the **right hand side** of a `-` is `nil`. e.g.

```
irb(main):001:0> 5 - nil
TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
        from (irb):1:in `-'
        from (irb):1
```

From your code the only possible example of this I can see is `guestStayedDays = departureDate - guest.arrived` so I would check the value of `guest.arrived`.

If something on the **left hand side** of a `-` were `nil` e.g. `departureDate` or `plot` then you would get `undefined method '-' for nil:NilClass` instead.

Comment: Yes you are correct line 91 points to: guestStayedDays = departureDate - guest.arrived. Your answer confirms then my suspicion. So then the value must be nil I suppose?

Comment: Correct. From the error you're seeing it must be `guest.arrived` that is `nil`. `guest` is not `nil` because you are successfully calling `arrived` on it, and `departureDate` is not `nil` because you are successfully calling `-` on that. It's the argument to `-` (`guest.arrived` that is the problem.)

Comment: Thank you mikej for your answers. I will try and see if I can solve this somehow.

Comment: I still cant seem to figure out why guest.arrived is nil. Could it have something to do with the fact that the self.check_out method is a class method and that arrived is saved in the self.check_in method?! Might be talking total mambo jambo here but Im a real newbie to Ruby:) I mean i still initilize guest=$camping.current_guests[plot-1] in this method. Help please!

Comment: If you email me a copy of the complete program (contact details in [my profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/63034/mikej)) and the steps to get the error I'll take a quick look. We can then edit the question to add the pertinent details in case they're of interest to anyone else in the future.

Comment: Wow! Thanks mikej. I have emailed you at your .org email. Really nice of you!