# Help `-': nil can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [`-': nil can’t be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407016/nil-cant-be-coerced-into-fixnum-typeerror)

Does anyone know how come guest.arrived can be nil?! This is a small part of my checkout method I have in my program. The error points at line 91 in the code which is the last part of this block of code:

```
departureDate = gets.chomp.to_i
guest.departure = departureDate
guestStayedDays = departureDate - guest.arrived # Days the guest have stayed
```

I cant seem to figure this out. Is the problem with get.chomp.to_i that it is returning nil? Or is it returning 0? But then again that would not have given me this error. So is it guest that is nil or is it actually the combination guest.arrived that is the problem? Worth mentioning is that arrived is declared in my checkin method where the guest states its arrival date. Is it somehow lost?

Thanks for the answers I will post the checkin method aswell:

```
def self.check_in
    puts "Welcome to the checkin"
    puts "Please state your first name: "
    firstName = gets.chomp
    puts "Please state your last name:"
    lastName = gets.chomp
    puts "Write your address: "
    address = gets.chomp
    puts "and your phone number: "
    phone = gets.chomp
    puts "finally, your arrival date!"
    arrived = gets.chomp.to_i
    newPLot = $camping.generateParkingLot
    guest = Guest.new(firstName, lastName, address, phone, arrived)
    $camping.current_guests[newPLot-1] = guest
    $camping.all_guests.push(guest)   # lägg till gästen i historiken         

    puts "The registration was a success!! You have received plot " + newPLot.to_s + "."    
  end
```

Here the arrived variable is defined and when I in my checkout method do puts $camping.current_guests i see all the info. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You already asked this *exact same* question yesterday and the answer is still the *exact same* answer: the problem is that the `arrived` method of `guest` returns `nil` and unless you actually *show* the code of that method, there is nothing anyone can do about it.

Comment: I now posted the checkin method as well hoping thats what you were referring to when you asked about the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `guest.arrived` is returning nil.

- If `guest` was the `nil`, then you'd have an error on line 90 saying

  ```
  NoMethodError: undefined method `departure=' for nil:NilClass
  ```
- If `departureDate` was `nil` then you'd get an error on line 91 saying

  ```
  NoMethodError: undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass
  ```

  Besides that, the `to_i` function used on the first line always returns a number -- even if you got `nil` or `""` from somewere else, `nil.to_i` and `"".to_i` both return zero.
- If the `guest.arrived` didn't exist, you'd also get a `NoMethodError`.

Comment: Hmm I see what you mean. When you put it like that its obvious. But then again Im puzzled, am I "addressing" it wrong then by saying guest.arrived?! As it is in a self method that should be a class method(if u can say that in Ruby). What Im trying to say is that it feels that somehow in between self.check_in and self.check_out Im losing data.