# '*' can't be coerced into Fixnum(TypeError)

Tags: ruby, typeerror

I'm trying to write a program to do factorials. I made this:

```
continue_loop=true

def fact(n)
  if n==0
    1
  else
    n*fact(n-1)
  end
end

while continue_loop
  puts "Welcome to the factorial machine. Write a number! Write exit to exit the program"
  user=gets.chomp
  if user=="exit"
    continue_loop=false
  else puts fact(user.to_i)
    puts "--------"
  end
end
```

I get `* can't be coerced into Fixnum(TypeError)` on lines:

```
n*fact(n-1)
```

and

```
else puts fact(user.to_i)
```

I found that I get this error because the right hand side of `n*fact(n-1)` is `nil`. But then, I don't see how I can do recursion.

It can be done with `inject`, but I'd like to learn to use recursion.

Comment: Your program seems to be fine, I just copy pasted it and it worked perfectly well. Could you try to reproduce this in an online interpreter?
https://repl.it/languages/ruby

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa Thanks for the editting and sorry for my mistakes, English is not my native language and as you can see I'm quite new to programming). I'll try not to make them in future questions (as well as including the actual question).

Comment: @DanielPerez it seems like the problem is in my interpreter, because it works online... Thank you.

Comment: *... the right hand side of `n*fact(n-1)` is `nil`* How does the right hand side become `nil`? What value is being passed to `fact(n)` when you get the error? And when you say you think the problem is your interpreter, what interpreter are you using?

Comment: @lurker I found that in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407016/nil-cant-be-coerced-into-fixnum-typeerror?rq=1) thread with the - operation. I'm using the Command Prompt.

Comment: "Command Prompt" isn't a Ruby interpreter. What are you running to interpret Ruby? `irb`? Something else? If the problem were that `nil` was on the right hand side, then I would expect the error to be that `nil` cannot be coerced into `Fixnum` rather than `*`.

Comment: @lurker Yes, it's `irb`. I restarted the command prompt and it works now, but I still don't know where did that error come from. Thanks for your  time and answers, I'm such a newbie I'm ashamed now.

Comment: No need to be ashamed! In solving any problem online it's good to be precise so that others can tell exactly what led to the problem and can assist more effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function:

```
def  fact(n)
    if n==0
        1
    else
       n*fact(n-1)
    end
end
```

is fine. `if/else` returns values from both blocks. Just to be sure I just tried with `fact(5)` and it returned `120`. If something were wrong, it would not. Of course, your function `fact(-1)` fails badly, but that's another problem.

Your function cannot return nil. It will either return 1 or result of multiplication. Therefore in `n*fact(n-1)` the right hand can't be nil. The left hand probably is. Find out why.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't see how the left hand side can be `nil`.

Comment: @Lenok:To be honest, I blindly assumed that `user.to_i` will generate a faulty value when some trash is inputted. I didn't think that it would be `nil` though. However, I checked your code and it works fine even for trash input (except for negatives, where it gets stack-overflow). Then I remembered that `to_i` returns `0` when conversion can't be made, so, well, there's no nil here, ever. Now that I reread the error message, it claims that `*` cant be converted, not `nil`. This could indicate that the `n` could be == to `"*"` (a string with asterisk) or something of similar level of weirdness.

Comment: but even when I tried that, the `to_i` simply returned `0` as it does for garbage input. So, I don't know. Since your program started working after rebooting IRB, then that had to be some accidental damage to that session (something like accidental redefining some basic method like &:* or to_s). Or maybe some bug in IRB? Sorry, out of ideas.